# Rails specify load order of javascript files?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, asset-pipeline

In my application.js file, I have:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require underscore
//= require backbone
//= require_tree .
//
//= require .//community_app
//
//= require_tree ../templates/
//= require_tree .//models
//= require_tree .//collections
//= require_tree .//views
//= require_tree .//routers
```

but the generated html doesn't obey this order:

```
<head>
  <title>CommunityApp</title>
  <link href="/assets/application.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/communities.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/home.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/underscore.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/backbone.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/collections/communities.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/community_app.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/home.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/models/community.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/application.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <meta content="authenticity_token" name="csrf-param" />
<meta content="ktrLMDYSJaU/mmgmzfpxDfMin7OCXga4K5gVIJZHJUI=" name="csrf-token" />
</head>
<body>
```

Collections is loaded before the model which gives me error on the front-end. How can I make it so it loads in a specific manner the js files?
thanks

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You've still got a

```
//= require_tree .
```

Higher up, which is loading everything, apparently in alphabetical order. Remove that (obviously making sure that everything is required elsewhere) and you should be fine. You might be able to make that the last line of your application.js but I don't remember the specified behaviour when two statements end up requiring the same file

Comment: Thanks for the input. Is there a way I can make require_tree not load in alphabetical? What's the proper way to do this?

Comment: @0xSina: The proper way to specify a specific order is to, well, specify the order by hand like you're (almost) doing.

Comment: I'd remove the ` require_tree .` and require things in the desired order (possibly using require_tree in subfolders)

Comment: [From the guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#manifest-files-and-directives): "Note that the family of require directives prevents files from being included twice in the output." You can list the ones that need a special order and can still use `require_tree .` _after_ those. Works for me.