# Ruby on Rails- best way to include multiple js library files in my app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm building a Rails app and I wish to include the [Pages](http://pages.revox.io/) library for my frontend. The library includes multiple js files and it looks like I'll be needing all of them (there are more than 30 .js files).

What is the best way I can include them in my application.js file? From what it looks like, my options are:

1. Copy code from each file and paste it in `application.js` IN ORDER (the very same reason I can't use `//=require_tree` as it [interprets each file in alphabetical order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11285941/rails-specify-load-order-of-javascript-files)). This is not recommended, as written in the file itself.
2. Rename each file individually so that the order is alphabetical and `//=require_tree` collects them in alphabetical order (very cumbersome!)

I'm confident that there has to be a better way because I'm not the first person to want to include large libraries in my project. What is the approach I should follow?

Answer (score 1):

I think there is nothing like one best approach but I've ended up in a pretty good approach to manage assets in rails going behind performance. Never use *require_tree* unless your app have only few assets to afford it.

Every template will have two set of assets. One is ***core assets*** which should be needed throughout the app like *bootstrap* and the other one is ***page specific assets*** like *jquery lightbox* for gallery page alone. 
 Adding all your assets in application js makes them to load on all pages, but rails have clean solutions to deal with this.

**1.** First copy all your assets to `vendor/assets/javscripts` and `vendor/assets/stylesheets`folder. If you are using *rails 5.1+*, the assets folder is removed from vendor, if you wish the good old convention, you can create *`assets/javascripts`* and `assets/stylesheet` folder and add them to precompile in `config/initializers/assets.rb` or from 5.1+ I prefer copying everything from the template's assets folder to vendor folder. This is up to you.
**2.** Include all your `core assets` in `application.js` and `application.css`. It's better to move the `javascript_include_tag` in `application.html.erb` from header to just above the `</body>` tag. You might need to keep `jquery` alone in header if you want to write jquery in view files.
3. To add page specific js, create a js file with controller name. ie, for `homes_controller`, create a `homes.js` in app/assets/javascripts. Then replace.

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application'%>
```

in application.html.erb with

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', params[:controller] %>
```

This will load the js with controller name, along with application js. You can `//require` assets for this controller or write js for this controller views alone in this file.For this to work you need to add this file to precompile in assets.rb. Instead for adding individual files, just `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile << /(^[^_\/]|\/[^_])[^\/]*$/` to assets.rb which will precompile all the assets.
Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can follow the simple steps because this is the very easy way look below.

**Step 1.**  You can create a folder inside `assets/javascripts` it looks like `assetes/javascripts/modules` or anything that actually you like instead of the `modules` then all JS files upload into the newly created folder.

**Step 2.** Then `application.js` just include that files like `//= require modules/file_name` include all files like that

That's it, I think this is quite easy.

> Note: You can also upload all files inside `rails_project/vendor/assets/javascripts/`

Hope to help

Comment: No, this will require all the js files in alphabetical order inside the modules folder. I can't have that because that will give errors. I need to include them in the specific order the library's source code has included them.